# Struggling to find a way to make Tkinter Listbox have a button that deletes corresponding item in an array

Tags: python, tkinter

First off, this is kind of a hard to explain problem, but I will take a crack at it.

I have created an array with some *'items'* in it and have put those items from that array (using a for loop so that no matter how many items may be in the array it still works) into a listbox where you can select one of the items to delete. However because I used a for loop, the items in the listbox don't have a number I can associate with them and so i can't delete the one item that I want.

Below is the code I am using at the moment:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
global num
num = 1

inventorylist = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]

def remove():
   global i
   del inventorylist[i]
   situation_I()


def situation_IR():
   global num
   if num == 1:
       windowi.destroy()
       num = 2

   global windowir
   windowir = Tk()
   windowir.title( "IR" )

   listframe = Frame( windowir )
   listbox = Listbox( listframe )

   global i

   for i in range(len(inventorylist)):
       e = i+1
       listbox.insert(e, inventorylist[i])


   btn_ir_1 = Button( listframe, text = "Remove", command = remove )
   btn_ir_1.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 5)

   listbox.pack(side = LEFT)

   listframe.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)


   windowir.mainloop


def situation_I():
   global num

   if num == 2:
       windowir.destroy()
       num = 1

   global windowi
   windowi = Tk()
   windowi.title( "I" )

   Btn_i = Button( windowi, text = "Remove item", command = situation_IR )
   Btn_i.grid( row = 61, column = 76, columnspan = 50 )

   Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
   Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )

   all_lines = []

   for i in range(0, len(inventorylist), 3):
       line = ", ".join(inventorylist[i:i+3])
       all_lines.append(line)

   words = ",\n".join(all_lines)

   Label_i.configure( text = words )


   windowi.mainloop()



situation_I()
```

At the moment it just deletes the last item in the array no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, use `curselection()` to find the index of the selected item, the code is given below and I hope that it solves your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):
    list = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        box = tk.Listbox(self)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Remove', command = lambda: self.rmv(box))
        for item in Root.list: box.insert(tk.END, item)
        box.pack(side = 'top')
        btn.pack(side = 'bottom')

    def rmv(self, *args):
        box, = args
        try:
            ind = box.curselection()[0]
            del Root.list[ind] #To delete values in the list too. 
            box.delete(ind)
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Root().mainloop()
```